# How to extract Information?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

Objective: I am trying to do a project on Natural Language Processing (NLP), where I want to extract information and represent it in graphical form.

Description:

1. I am considering news article as input to my project.
2. Removing unwanted data in the input & making it in Clean Format.
3. Performing NLP & Extracting Information/Knowledge
4. Representing Information/Knowledge in Graphical Format.

Is it Possible?

Comment: try NLTK. You can also use Stanford CoreNLP its also good, I've tried it on a similar project.

Comment: That is probably possible, once you specify what kind of information you want to extract from the input data. There is no magic "get me all kinds of information" method, however (that is probably impossible, too).

Comment: I am trying with NLTK but i got confused on how perform NameEntity Recognition (actually didn't understand).

Comment: Before you explore the solution, you need to pose the right question. 1. News article is only the article or the whole webpage or meta information? 2. What is unwanted data according to you? 3/4. What exactly you want to show?

Answer (score 0):

If want to use nltk, you can start [here](http://textminingonline.com/dive-into-nltk-part-v-using-stanford-text-analysis-tools-in-python). Its has some explanation about tokenizing, Part Of Speech Tagging, Parsing and more.

Check this [page](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html) for an example of named entity detection using nltk.

The Graphical representation can be performed using [igraph](http://www.cs.rhul.ac.uk/home/tamas/development/igraph/tutorial/tutorial.html) or [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/).

Also, scikit-learn has a great [text feature extraction](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html) methods, in case you want to run some more sophisticated models.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to try and do this job yourself by hand with a pencil.  Try it on not just one but a collection of news stories.  You really do have to do this and not just think about it.  Draw the graphics just as you'd want the computer to.

What this does is forces you to create rules about how information is transformed to graphics.   This is NOT always possible, so doing it by hand is a good test.  If you can't do it then you can't program a computer to do it.

Assuming you have found a paper and pencil method.   What I like to do is work BACKWARDS.   Your method starts with the text.  No.  Start with the numbers you need to draw the graphic.   Then you think about where are these numbers in the stories and what words do I have to look at to get these numbers. Your job is now more like a hunting trip, you know the data is there, but how to find it.

Sorry for the lack of details but I don't know your exact problem but this works in every case.  First learn to do the job yourself on paper then work backwards from the output to the input.

If you try to design this software in the forward direction you get stuck soon because you can't possibly know what to do with your text because you don't know what you need, it's like pushing a rope it don't work.  Go to the other end and pull the rope.  Do the graphic work FIRST then pull the needed data from the news stories.